# Find root of $x^2 + bx + c$ with an approximation for $b$

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

I have a monic quadratic equation $x^2 + bx + c$, where $b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$ for which I need to compute the roots. $x$ is also an integer. However, I don't have the exact value of $b$, only an approximation. For concreteness, say I know the most significant $\frac{3}{4}$ digits of $b$, but not the rest. Is there any way to find the roots that's faster than trying every value in the range given by the approximation?

EDIT: I also know that $b \leq \sqrt{c}$.

Comment: Um, if you don't know what b is how will you know if you find a root whether it is a root or not?  I mean, if I'm told to find the solution for $x = b$ but I'm told what b is, how can I possibly know if what I have is an answer or not.

Comment: I don't understand quite what you're asking.

Comment: Are you assuming that $x$ is an integer too. Like this is a Diophantine equation ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  If you don't know what the equation is then you can't solve it.  Find the roots to *what*?  You don't have an equation to find the roots of.

Comment: Okay.  Say your equation is 5x^2 + bx + 7 and b is between 53 and 59.  Well each value of b will have *different* roots.  You say you don't want to try each one to see if it works.  Well, *all* of them will work if you set b to that value.  The only way to tell if a potential root "works" is if you have an actual equation to check.  Your question makes absolutely no sense at all.  You say how do you find the roots.  Find the roots to WHAT?

Comment: Yeah, $x$ is also an integer. Forgot to mention that, sorry.

Comment: @Paul Not if $b$ is negative. For example, $x^2-6x+9$ has the integer root $3$.

Comment: Mea culpa - I was interpreting it as $|b| \le \sqrt{c}$, but that is clearly not what was said.